# display two files horizontally in the shell

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, cat

file 1:

```
dsf
sdfsd
dsfsdf
```

file 2:

```
sdfsdfsd
sdfsdsdfsdf
dsfsdfsdfsdf
```

I want to cat two files horizontally so the result is:

```
dsf        sdfsdfsd
sdfsd      sdfsdsdfsdf
dsfsdf     dsfsdfsdfsdf
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `paste` command as:

```
paste file1 file2
```

Demo:

```
$ cat file1
1
2
3
$ cat file2
3
4
5
$ paste file1 file2
1   3
2   4
3   5
$
```

The default character used as delimiter is tab. If you want some other character say space, you can use the `-d` option as:

```
paste -d ' ' file1 file2
```